# Solve integral(convolution) equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, integral-equations

I have been trying to find a solution to the following convolution equation:
\begin{align*}
e^{-ax^2/2}*\ln \left(f(x)*e^{-ax^2/2}\right)+e^{-bx^2/2}*\ln \left(f(x)*e^{-bx^2/2}\right)=cx^2
\end{align*}
I am trying to solve for $f(x)$ where $a,b,c$ are constants. Note,that '*' denotes convolution. We can assume that $f(x)>0$ and $f(x) \in L^1$.

I have been attempting to use Fourier analysis method but so far unsuccessful.
For example I have found that 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}\left (\ln(f(t)\right)=\frac{1}{i\omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\right)
\end{align*}
Applying this we get 
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a} }e^{-\omega^2/(2a)} \mathcal{F} \left(\ln \left(f(x)*e^{-ax^2/2}\right) \right)+ \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{b} }e^{-\omega^2/(2b)} \mathcal{F} \left(\ln \left(f(x)*e^{-bx^2/2}\right) \right)=-2\pi c \delta^{(2)}(\omega)
\end{align*}
by using $\mathcal{F}\left (\ln(f(t)\right)=\frac{1}{i\omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\right)$ we get

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{a} }e^{-\omega^2/(2a)} \frac{1}{i\omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{f(x)*(-ax)e^{-ax^2/2}}{f(x)*e^{-ax^2/2}}\right)+ \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{b} }e^{-\omega^2/(2b)} \frac{1}{i\omega} \mathcal{F} \left( \frac{f(x)*(-bx)e^{-bx^2/2}}{f(x)*e^{-bx^2/2}}\right)=-2\pi c \delta^{(2)}(\omega)
\end{align*}
But how do I proceed now?

I am also looking for any related reference. Is also reminds of functional equations, but I am don't know much in that area.
 Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Without applying  a lot of time to this problem yet, I can say that under suitable conditions the Fourier transform of a convolution can be simply stated as the pointwise product of the Fourier transforms, therefore in prionciple your method seems ok to me.

Comment: This is what I think as well. I have added my results on that approach. If you have any other pointers I would be very gratful.

Comment: What space all these functions belong to and how the convolution and $ln$ are to be understood? If we suppose that the convolution is defined in normal sense and $ln(...)$ lies in $L_1$, then by Lebesgue's theorem the left side tends to zero, while the right one tends to infinity, when $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I added that $f^L^{1+}$. But I don't think that $ln(..)$ lies in $L=^1$.